# Having a Node.JS Express template engine with multiple templates in one file

Tags: node.js, templates, express, template-engine

I wrote a custom template engine to let me use my old templates in a rewrite of my current project. Everything is working except that Express.js always sends a

```
Error: Failed to lookup view (template name)
```

I have multiple templates in one file and I don't need one file for each template. But how can I tell that to Express?

I can't get my head around this.
Any help is appreciated

**EDIT:** Some Code:

```
My Express Setup: (app.js)

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var gclosure = require('./templateEngine');
var fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Setup Express
 */
app.configure(function(){

    app.engine('test', gclosure.__express);

    app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/templates');
    app.set('view engine', 'test');

    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

    app.use(require('less-middleware')({
        src: __dirname + '/public'
    }));

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

My Custom Template Engine (templateEngine.js)

```
exports.renderFile =  function(path, options, fn){

  if ('function' == typeof options) {
    fn = options, options = {};
  }

  try {

    fm(null, "This is a test output");

  } catch (err) {
    fn(err);
  }
};
```

My test route in express:

```
  app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    res.render('simple',{
              title: 'Sources',
              data: 'lala',
              options: 'miep'
          }); 

  });
```

The Clue is: When I create a file named `simple.test` in the template folder everything is working and I can see the test output string. When I change the name to something that doesn't exist the out put is

```
Error: Failed to lookup view (template name)
```

Comment: You really need to show us some more code so please, elaborate!

Comment: I do not have a crystal ball, so I cannot see your code.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I added my example code. TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:**

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) uses the template [engine](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.engine) to create a view object which renders the view. Since the view itself is created by looking up the file into the filesystem the template engine has no way of telling express that it handles the files on its own.

**The Solution:**

Instead of using a template engine approach I wrote a [custom middle-ware](https://github.com/johnnycube/gclosure-node) that intercepts calls to my template engine depending on the name of the template function. Basically I overwrite the `response.render()` function in [express](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render).

---

**Update:** [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/johnnycube/gclosure-node)

Comment: Since you asked so nicely and gave a downvote before even considering asking nicely: No can doeseville

Comment: I'm currently writing a github project to feature this middleware. Since this middleware is tailored towards Google Closure Templates there maybe is some need to make it work with your desired template engine. But it should point you in the right direction. Give me a couple of days, because I'm in the middle of moving from one city to another.

Comment: Open source community people are putting efforts to help others as well, So When you get time please do it. -Thanks

Comment: Open source people help others as well...like you are helping me!? I dont get your attitude - or maybe you just come off rude right away. Anywho: here is the repository https://github.com/johnnycube/gclosure-node